# Stored Procedures Network/Client traffic

Tags: sql, t-sql

Use of stored procedures can reduce network traffic between clients and servers, because the commands are executed as a single batch of code. This means only the call to execute the procedure is sent over a network, instead of every single line of code being sent individually.

What is this network traffic between clients and server? 
Can someone make me understand with some **real time example?**

Thank You

Comment: `Server` here means the SQL Server itself. In production systems, SQL Server is usually installed on a dedicated machine. `Client` means whatever application is executing the stored procedure - it can be SSMS, or a website's server side, a service, or a desktop application. The `network traffic` means, then - the traffic between the computer on which the `client` is running and the computer on which the `server` is running.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have 10 different aggregate tables which need to be calculated (truncated and re-calculated) every now and then, and the code to do this requires 200 lines of TSQL. If you issue this command through a client over the network, you will have to send all 200 lines of code to the server.

If you create a stored procedure that contains the script to do this, then the client will only need to send 1 line of code; the one that executes the stored procedure. This is just one benefit of using stored procedures, there are many more (script is already compiled, better security handling, etc.).

The time saved by doing this change will greatly depend on the size of the script/batch you are trying to execute and the network connection between client and server. It's not the same sending this command from an Application Server to the Database Server in the same Data Warehouse than sending it from a SSMS in Singapore connected to a SQL Server database in Italy.